# SQL getting the minimum out of calculation of 3 values

Tags: sql

I have multiple rows that each have 3 columns and what I want to do is calculate these 3 columns at each row and see which row has the lowest sum

for example:

```
row 1 - col1(1)+col2(3)+col3(0) = 4
row 2 - col1(50) + col2(3) + col3(4) = 57
row 3 - col1(2) + col2(0) + col3(0) = 2
```

the selected row (row 3) will show me the calculated value = 2

currently I have been calculating only by 1 column but now I need 3

this is what I was doing:

```
select min(Bonus) from dbo.Bonuses AS c1
```

my table (Bonuses)

```
ID      Bonus    Double Bonus   Master Bonus
1         1          3              0
2         50         3              4
3         2          0              0
```

expected results:

the row 3 is the minimum in value will print

```
2
```

Comment: share table data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with:

```
select min(col1 + col2 + col3) from table;
```

`col1 + col2 + col3` - calculate sum of every line (row) of the table;

`min(col1 + col2 + col3)` - determine minimal value.
In your case:

```
select min("Bonus" + "Double Bonus" + "Master Bonus") from "Bonuses";
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoul get the minimum among columns first, for each row, then get the minimum from result column:

```
select min(least(col1, col2, col3)) from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, you should know that `NULL` values could have an unexpected result.  The safer calculation is:

```
select min(coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0) + coalesce(col3, 0))
```

The issue with `NULL` values is that the `+` returns `NULL` if *any* values are `NULL`.  That means that all values from that row would be ignored.

The sample data in the question doesn't have `NULL` values.  But it also doesn't specify that the values are never `NULL`, so I think this is important to point out.